# Is there an andand for Perl?

Tags: perl, andand

I'd rather do this:

```
say $shop->ShopperDueDate->andand->day_name();
```

vs. this:

```
say $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name() if $shop->ShopperDueDate;
```

Any ideas?

(This idea is inspired by the Ruby [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) extension.)

(Actually it is inspired by the Groovy language, but most people don't know that ;-)

**update**: I think that both maybe() and eval {} are good solutions.  This isn't ruby so I can't expect to read all of the methods/functions from left to right anyway, so maybe could certainly be a help.  And then of course eval really is the perl way to do it.

Comment: You also posted this to Perlmonks (http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=734774). Please let people know when you are posting the same question to multiple places so people can see all of the answers and not waste time answering when you've got your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've just written it. I've just uploaded it to CPAN, you can find it [here](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Andand).

Comment: Can you expand on "you can't call methods on undefined values"?  I'm not completely sure you read all of my post.

Comment: undefined values can not be blessed references and as such you can't call methods on them. It requires quite a bit of magic to make that work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Perl's `eval` statement to catch exceptions, including those from trying to call methods on an undefined argument:

```
eval {
    say $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name();
};
```

Since `eval` returns the last statement evaluated, or `undef` on failure, you can record the day name in a variable like so:

```
my $day_name = eval { $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name(); };
```

If you actually wish to inspect the exception, you can look in the special variable `$@`.  This will usually be a simple string for Perl's built-in exceptions, but may be a full exception object if the exception originates from [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) or other code that uses object exceptions.

```
eval {
    say $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name();
};

if ($@) {
    say "The error was: $@";
}
```

It's also possible to string together a sequence of commands using an `eval` block.  The following will only check to see if it's a weekend provided that we haven't had any exceptions thrown when looking up `$day_name`.

```
eval {
    my $day_name = $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name();

    if ($day_name ~~ [ 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ] ) {
        say "I like weekends";
    }
};
```

You can think of `eval` as being the same as `try` from other languages; indeed, if you're using the [Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Error) module from the CPAN then you can even spell it `try`.  It's also worth noting that the block form of eval (which I've been demonstrating above) doesn't come with performance penalties, and is compiled along with the rest of your code.  The string form of `eval` (which I have not shown) is a different beast entirely, and should be used sparingly, if at all.

`eval` is technically considered to be a statement in Perl, and hence is one of the few places where you'll see a semi-colon at the end of a block.  It's easy to forget these if you don't use `eval` regularly.

*Paul*

Answer (score 9):

I assume your second example should better be:

```
say $shop->ShopperDueDate ? $shop->ShopperDueDate->day_name() : undef;
```

instead of what it actually says.

Anyway, you can't do it with *exactly* that syntax without a source filter because `undef` isn't an object, but an unary operator, so it can't have any methods.

Instead, consider this:

```
package noop; 
our $maybe = bless [], 'noop';
sub AUTOLOAD { undef };
```

This `$noop::maybe` is an object; all of its methods return `undef` though. Elsewhere, you'll have a regular function like this:

```
sub maybe { $_[0] || $noop::maybe; }
```

Then you can write this:

```
say maybe($shop->ShopperDueDate)->day_name()
```

This works because "maybe" returns returns its argument if true, otherwise it returns our `$noop::maybe` object which has methods which always return undef.

*EDIT*: Correction! the `->andand->` syntax *can* be had without a source filter, by using an [XS](http://search.cpan.org/src/CHOCOLATE/autobox-2.55/autobox.xs) that mucks about with Perl's internals. [Leon Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422837/is-there-an-andand-for-perl#424902) made an implementation that takes this route. It replaces the `undef()` function globally, so it's likely to be a lot slower than my method.

Comment: Why do you say that would be better?  It's exactly the same right?

Comment: The order to read them makes a bit more sense in his example, IMHO

Comment: Frew: The first example is say($some_value) where the second example is roughly equivalent to if($some_value){say($some_value)} - the former example always has say() being called, whereas the latter makes calling say() conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested):

```
use Object::Generic::False;
sub UNIVERSAL::andand { $_[0] || Object::Generic::False->false }
```

UNIVERSAL is automatically a subclass of all other classes, so this provides andand for all objects.
(Obviously creating methods in UNIVERSAL has the potential for conflicts or surprising action at a distance,
so it shouldn't be used carelessly.)  If the object upon which the andand method is called is true, return it;
otherwise return a generic false object which returns itself for any method call used upon it.

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't call methods on undefined values.

Comment: If desired, one can always use the autobox pragma to promote the undefined value to a first class object.  Then you *can* call methods on it. ;)